# bad interpreter: Permission denied, Cygwin

Tags: permissions, cygwin, permission-denied

Iam working on compile file and need to execute it by cygwin
so I browsed the folder,
content of compile file

\rm subs.a
./BUILD_subs
./BUILD_progs

then

./ compile

the result

./compile: ./BUILD_subs: /bin/csh: bad interpreter: Permission denied
./compile: ./BUILD_progs: /bin/csh: bad interpreter: Permission denied

can anyone give me some inflammations , what is going on >